# p:commandlink url not getting refreshed

Tags: primefaces

Iam using p:commandlink for my menulinks..
the problem is that url in the browser is not getting refreshed with the page provided in th action..

Here goes my code...

any help

```
                    <li><a href="#">Masters</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><p:commandLink action="ParcelMaster1.xhtml" value="ParcelMaster" /></li>
                            <li><p:commandLink action="ZoneMaster1.xhtml" value="ZoneMaster" ajax="false"/></li>
                            <li><p:commandLink action="PropertyFlatMaster1.xhtml" value="PropertyFlatMaster" ajax="false"/></li>
                            <li><p:commandLink action="WardMaster1.xhtml" value="WardMaster" ajax="false"/></li>
                            <li><p:commandLink action="MaMaster1.xhtml" value="MAMaster" ajax="false"/></li>
                            <li><p:commandLink action="PropertyParentMaster.xhtml" value="PropertyParentMaster" ajax="false"/></li>
                            <li><a href="" title="">Usage Types</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" title="">Custom Types</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `ajax = "false"` to your `commandLink`. It is by default ajax call and it cannot redirect. Also try adding `?faces-redirect=true` to url to which you are redirecting.